# Pass a variable to a template .phtml block in Magento

Tags: magento, block, php

This code is write in market.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setData('vendorId',$vendor->getCustomerId())->setTemplate('marketplace/vendors/badge.phtml')->toHtml();?>
```

In Badge.php

```
echo $this->vendorId;
```

But my output is null. Is this correct way to pass data to block?

Comment: are you sure you are getting value in $vendor->getCustomerId() ?

Comment: How are you using Badge.php? It seems like in your template you are instantiating a `core/template` block. Please show us more info about how your extension is defined.

Comment: @PradeepSanku yes i m getting value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change your variable like this and check it

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setVendorId($vendor->getCustomerId())->setTemplate('marketplace/vendors/badge.phtml')->toHtml();?>
```

Now you can access this vendor ID variable in badge.phtml file like this :

```
<?php echo $this->getVendorId();?>
```